# How do i fix the buttons close minimize maximize?

Tags: compiz, interface

sometimes the bar with close minimize maximize buttons dissapears im using 11.10 I messed with compiz once and deleted it it fixed the problem, but its back now

it seems the bar crashes sometimes

Comment: By the "bar", are referring to the window titlebars, the Unity panel, or both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Unity, run `unity --reset` in a terminal. It will preserve your shortcuts (since 11.10), but reset your other settings (compiz profile that is).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using unity or gnome shell? because in gnome shell you get no minimize/maximize buttons by default.

If you are using gnome shell, install gnome-tweak-tool. There will be options in there.

Comment: Asking for additional information should be done via comments instead, thanks! :-) I'm aware that you cannot post comments until you reach 50 reputation, but that's how the site works -unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

reinstall the compiz program again, and restore the default settings from the same program, to reset you settings